# How can Plot (time series plot) monthly temperatures from Jan to Dec for the years(1880-2017)?

Tags: r, plot

Below is a part of the data frame, the timeline actually from 1880-2017

```
     Year   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1   1880 -0.29 -0.18 -0.11 -0.19 -0.11 -0.23 -0.21 -0.09 -0.16 -0.23 -0.20 -0.23
2   1881 -0.15 -0.17  0.04  0.04  0.02 -0.20 -0.06 -0.02 -0.13 -0.20 -0.21 -0.10
3   1882  0.15  0.15  0.04 -0.18 -0.16 -0.26 -0.20 -0.05 -0.10 -0.24 -0.16 -0.24
4   1883 -0.31 -0.39 -0.13 -0.17 -0.20 -0.12 -0.08 -0.15 -0.20 -0.14 -0.22 -0.16
5   1884 -0.15 -0.08 -0.37 -0.42 -0.36 -0.40 -0.34 -0.26 -0.27 -0.24 -0.30 -0.28
6   1885 -0.58 -0.30 -0.25 -0.42 -0.42 -0.44 -0.35 -0.31 -0.23 -0.19 -0.19 -0.05
7   1886 -0.42 -0.45 -0.38 -0.27 -0.26 -0.38 -0.21 -0.33 -0.25 -0.28 -0.31 -0.26
8   1887 -0.72 -0.52 -0.34 -0.38 -0.32 -0.23 -0.23 -0.32 -0.22 -0.32 -0.23 -0.33
9   1888 -0.37 -0.36 -0.41 -0.22 -0.22 -0.18 -0.10 -0.16 -0.10  0.02  0.01 -0.06
10  1889 -0.11  0.18  0.08  0.07 -0.02 -0.14 -0.10 -0.20 -0.22 -0.22 -0.33 -0.30
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
mydata=mydata = read.csv("GLB.Ts_dSST.csv")
subset2=as.data.frame(t(mydata[,1:13])) 
plot(subset2$V1[2:13])
```

However, I can not get the line plot but the point plot. I know I can use "l" in plot function to change the type, but it will return

> "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths
>   differ".

Can anyone help me thanks!!!

Comment: Are you saying that you want one single line over all of the years?   In that case you will want to make a "long" data set with month-year in one column and the y values in the other.

Comment: please format this post properly. Maybe you should try `ts()` for setting you data as time-series and `plot.ts()`  or `ts.plot()` for plotting.

Comment: You should give us an example dataset wot work with. Use the function `dput(mydata[1:10, ] )` (to get the first 10 lines), copy the output and share it with us here.

Comment: Firstly, thank u guys. Then I gonna make monthly temperatures for every
two decades (1990,1920,.., 2000) and 2017 . So i suppose I need multiple lines with different colours in a single plot to show the difference between those years.  The x-axis should be Jan to Dec, and y-axis be the degrees

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). We can convert the data frame to long format and plot it.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  gather(Month, Degree, -Year) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, month.abb),
         Year = factor(Year))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Month, y = Degree, color = Year, group = Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set3") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

If you want to summarize data for multiple years as you mentioned in your comment, you can do the following.

```
dat3 <- dat %>% 
  gather(Month, Degree, -Year) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, month.abb),
         Year_Group = case_when(
           Year >= 1880 & Year <= 1882    ~"1880-1882",
           Year >= 1883 & Year <= 1885    ~"1883-1885",
           Year >= 1886 & Year <= 1889    ~"1886-1889"
         )) %>%
  group_by(Year_Group, Month) %>%
  summarise(Degree = mean(Degree))

ggplot(dat3, aes(x = Month, y = Degree, color = Year_Group, group = Year_Group)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "     Year   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1   1880 -0.29 -0.18 -0.11 -0.19 -0.11 -0.23 -0.21 -0.09 -0.16 -0.23 -0.20 -0.23
                  2   1881 -0.15 -0.17  0.04  0.04  0.02 -0.20 -0.06 -0.02 -0.13 -0.20 -0.21 -0.10
                  3   1882  0.15  0.15  0.04 -0.18 -0.16 -0.26 -0.20 -0.05 -0.10 -0.24 -0.16 -0.24
                  4   1883 -0.31 -0.39 -0.13 -0.17 -0.20 -0.12 -0.08 -0.15 -0.20 -0.14 -0.22 -0.16
                  5   1884 -0.15 -0.08 -0.37 -0.42 -0.36 -0.40 -0.34 -0.26 -0.27 -0.24 -0.30 -0.28
                  6   1885 -0.58 -0.30 -0.25 -0.42 -0.42 -0.44 -0.35 -0.31 -0.23 -0.19 -0.19 -0.05
                  7   1886 -0.42 -0.45 -0.38 -0.27 -0.26 -0.38 -0.21 -0.33 -0.25 -0.28 -0.31 -0.26
                  8   1887 -0.72 -0.52 -0.34 -0.38 -0.32 -0.23 -0.23 -0.32 -0.22 -0.32 -0.23 -0.33
                  9   1888 -0.37 -0.36 -0.41 -0.22 -0.22 -0.18 -0.10 -0.16 -0.10  0.02  0.01 -0.06
                  10  1889 -0.11  0.18  0.08  0.07 -0.02 -0.14 -0.10 -0.20 -0.22 -0.22 -0.33 -0.30",
                  header = TRUE)
```